# Wireless disconnects when laptop unplugged from power source

Tags: 11.10, wireless

My Ubuntu 11.10 laptop does not connect to my home router when the power source has been disconnected. When plugged back into the mains, the wireless starts working again.

I have a HP Pavilion dv6.

Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Power Manager is invoked when you switch to battery. `/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/wireless` (part of the `pm-utils` package) is what caused the same problem for me (Dell D630). I looked through the files in `dpkg -L pm-utils`, read `man pm-powersave` and found that I could disable the "feature" by creating `/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/wireless`.

So to fix this, open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and type:

```
sudo touch /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/wireless
```

Comment: Fantastic, thank you! Just to add, I had to restart Ubuntu afterwards, and then it worked great!

Answer (score 0):

According to `man pm-powersave`, if you want to disable the script for wireless, then type

```
sudo touch /etc/pm/power.d/wireless
```

I look forward to one day where the pm-utils will be fixed (for once and all)!

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here

there is a number of different things to try

here is how i fixed the problem

in terminal

```
iwconfig wlan0
```

your output

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:"YOURSSID"  ACCESSPOINT INFO  
          Bit Rate=58.5 Mb/s   Tx-Power=15 dBm  
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
         Power Management:on
          Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-30 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:28   Missed beacon:0
```

notice the power management on

if you see that here is how you fix this problem

again in terminal

```
 sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off
```

your new output

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:"YOURSSIDl"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.457 GHz  Access Point: YOURACCESSPOINT  
          Bit Rate=65 Mb/s   Tx-Power=15 dBm  
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
         Power Management:off
          Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-28 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:106  Invalid misc:29   Missed beacon:0
```

Notice power management is now off

This is caused by laptops excessive efforts to save power.

This worked with a dell laptop

latitude e6410

ubuntu 12.04 lts 64bit

do not waste your time with

```
sudo touch /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/wireless
```

or

```
sudo touch /etc/pm/power.d/wireless
```

those solves do not work