# **Wired** network disconnects when laptop unplugged

Tags: ethernet, disconnect

I am using Xubuntu 12.04 with Network Manager on my HP 5310m Laptop and get a weird problem on **wired** network.

When googling for answers, I found many people get the problem that **wireless** disconnects when laptop unplugged. For example, this question: [Wireless disconnects when laptop unplugged from power source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89238/wireless-disconnects-when-laptop-unplugged-from-power-source)

However, my problem is that my **wired** network of my laptop will auto disconnect when unplugged from a power source. Now if I want to use wired network, I must have my laptop plugged. If someone unplugged the power source of my laptop, my network connection will lost at the same time.

I think this may be some kind of "power-save" method but I searched `/etc/pm-utils/power.d/` without find anything about **wired** network.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/98936/wired-connection-not-working-unplugged-help

Comment: @Mitch Sorry, but I am not using a PPPoE connection. It's a Ethernet connection. And the problem occurs when I unplug the power source, not when powering up the laptop for some while...

Answer (score 1):

Well, I almost forgot that I asked here this question.

I have already figured out why. There is nothing to do with software, drivers, et cetra. This is indeed a hardware issue. The motherboard of my laptop will automatically turn off the wired NIC when unplugged. There is a switch in the CMOS setting named "Power save on LAN". Turning if off solves this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Wired or wireless works on the same way in NetworkManager daemon.
To avoid using it I had set up my own static eth connection for networking service in

```
/etc/network/interfaces<br/>

iface eth0 inet static<br/>
address 192.168.1.2<br/>
netmask 255.255.255.0<br/>
gateway 192.168.1.1<br/>
```

Then remove `eth dhcp` from the NetworkManager gui, otherwise it overrides it.

You can also set up dhcp there:
    auto eth0
    iface eth0 inet dhcp

If your `eth` is not `eth0`, you need to change here.