# Why does the WiFi disconnects when I plug my laptop?

Tags: 12.04, wireless

If I connect my laptop to the power the WiFi stops for every other devices on the same network but still works on my laptop...

I tried couple things like power management using `iwconfig` and some grub options like those: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_osi=Linux pcie_aspm=off`

I really don't know where to look to solve this problem. I thought it was an IP address conflict at first but it's really only when I connect the laptop to the power that other devices can't use internet anymore.

Thanks for the help.

edit: Forgot useful infos:

```
lspci | grep Wireless
03:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller (rev 01)
```

I'm using proprietary drivers.

Comment: Does anyone have any hints to give?

Comment: Does this solve your problem: http://askubuntu.com/questions/89238/wireless-disconnects-when-laptop-unplugged-from-power-source?